# How to access the IJobExecutionContext from a job inheriting from IDirectoryScanListener

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am using Quartz v2.2.3.400 downloaded from NuGet, .NET Framework v4.5, and using C#. I have several jobs that inherit from `IJob` and utilize the `IJobExecutionContext` object passed into the `Execute()` method. Those are working great. I also created a global job listener inheriting from `IJobListener` that logs every job that gets executed, again utilizing the `IJobExecutionContext` passed into the `JobToBeExecuted()`, `JobExecutionVetoed()`, and `JobWasExecuted()` methods.

Now for my question. I also have a few jobs that scan directories for new files, which inherit from `IDirectoryScanListener`. This interface defines a method signature void `FilesUpdatedOrAdded(IEnumerable<FileInfo> updatedFiles);` , which provides the file info for any new files in that directory since the last polling. That is great! However, I cannot seem to find a way to access this job's `IJobExecutionContext` , scheduler, etc. I would like to check some properties of the job's context and add data to the data map, but I am unable to without the `IJobExecutionContext`  being exposed. Is there a way that this can be accessed to my class that inherits from `IDirectoryScanListener`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really access the scheduler from a class implementing the IDirectoryScanListener interface. That interface only defines this method:

```
    public interface IDirectoryScanListener
    {
        ///<param name="updatedFiles">An array of <see cref="FileInfo"/> objects that were updated/added 
        ///since the last scan of the directory</param>
        void FilesUpdatedOrAdded(IEnumerable<FileInfo> updatedFiles);
    }
```

What you can do is create your own job that inherits from DirectoryScanJob. Then you'll have access to the context. It shouldn't be too much work. Just pass the context to the base class after you're done with it. Something like this:

```
    public class MyDirectoryScanJob:DirectoryScanJob
    {
        new public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            // You can access the context here
            base.Execute(context);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will check this out once I get to my development machine. Will I be able to access the updated file list via the JobDataMap in my class that inherits from IDirectoryScanListener? If I can, then this is a homerun

Comment: I think you're confusing some things. You don't inherit from IDirectoryScanListener, you implement that interface and no, in any class implementing that interface you don't have access to the job data map, but you do have access to the list of modified files. If you create a Job that inherits from DirectoryScanJob, then you will have access to the job data map BUT the list of files is not stored there. Only the last modified date is stored there. Take a look at this file: https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Job/DirectoryScanJob.cs

Comment: Makes sense. Yes 'implement' not 'inherit' from IDirectoryScanListener. I understand what your saying. This should work for me. Thanks for the github link.